# Reading /proc/<pid>/cmdline in C, getting different results each time

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to read /proc//cmdline.

The program is supposed to print out the PID, followed by the contents in /proc//cmdline. If the file is null it should print [].

For the process I tested in the screenshot below, it should be printing [] because there is nothing in the cmdline file. Instead, as you can see, it is printing some strange string (different every time). Is there something I'm doing wrong with scanning this file?

```
FILE* fp;
char buffer[256] = "";
char temp[256];
sprintf(buffer, "/proc/%s/cmdline", processId);
fp = fopen(buffer, "r");
fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", temp);
printf("[%s] ", temp);
fclose(fp);
```

[image]

Comment: Init the array 'char buffer[256] = {0};.

Comment: the `cmdline` does not end with a `\n'  so the statement; `fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", temp);` will fail

Comment: how does the posted code obtain the contents of `processId`?

Comment: the data bytes in the file: `cmdline` ends with a `]` Therefore suggest reading the data bytes until a `]` is encountered

Comment: the posted code never outputs the `processId` as a separate entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`processId` should be a `pid_t`; note the original posted code using `%s` instead of `%d`; the return values from `fopen()` and `fscanf()` were ignored; output from printing `temp` was probably showing uninitialized stack data.  Example version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[256], temp[256] = { 0 };
    pid_t processId;
    int ns;

    processId = getpid();
    sprintf(buffer, "/proc/%d/cmdline", processId);
    fp = fopen(buffer, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen() NULL, \"%s\"\n", buffer);
        return (1);
    }

    // consider what happens if cmdline content is larger than temp
    ns = fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", temp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("fscanf() returned %d\n", ns);
    printf("[%s] (%d)\n", temp, processId);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: this answer fails to limit the amount of data read via `fscanf()` and the last char in the `cmdline` is not a '\n' but rather a `]`,   Suggest: `ns = fscanf(fp, "%255[^]]", temp);`